# How to programmatically request media permissions?

Tags: javascript, getusermedia, twilio-video

Camera and microphone are manually blocked in Chrome (as shown in a picture below):
[image]

Local media tracks are created using **twilio-video** library methods **createLocalAudioTrack** and **createLocalVideoTrack** which throws the next exception:

```
DOMException: Permission denied
code: 0
message: "Permission denied"
name: "NotAllowedError"
```

When trying to use browser native getUserMedia as follows:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

it console logs the same exception in the catch block:

```
DOMException: Permission denied
```

**The question:** is it possible to know in advance, before creating local media tracks, that there are no permissions to do it (camera and microphone are manually blocked in a browser) and programmatically request such permissions (show popup requesting the permissions) to create the tracks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that, at the time I'm writing, this is still experimental territory

You can query permissions using [`Permissions.query()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions/query):

```js
const permissionDescriptors = [
  {name: 'camera'},
  {name: 'microphone'},
];

const permissions = await Promise.all(permissionDescriptors.map(async descriptor => ({
  descriptor,
  status: await navigator.permissions.query(descriptor),
})));

for (const {descriptor, status} of permissions) {
  console.log(
    descriptor.name, // 'camera' | 'microphone'
    status.state, // 'granted' | 'denied' | 'prompt'
  );
}
```

You will be able to request permissions using [`Permissions.request()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions/request). However, this is not currently supported in any browser.

Today, it's better to just try to access the [`MediaStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream), and catch and handle a potential exception:

```js
let mediaStream;
try {
  const constraints = { audio: true, video: true };
  mediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
}
catch (ex) {
  if (ex instanceof DOMException) {
    if (ex.name === 'NotAllowedError') {
      // handle permission denied
    }
    else if (ex.name === 'NotFoundError') {
      // handle media not found
    }
    else {
      // handle unexpected DOMException
    }
  }
  else {
    // handle unexpected error
  }
}

if (!mediaStream) {
  // handle no stream
}
else {
  // do something with stream
}
```

Comment: Exactly. Javascript can't determine gUM permissions without actually trying to use it, because otherwise it would be a covert way to fingerprint browsers ... a leakage of user preferences that should be kept private.

Comment: @O.Jones Permissions are origin-specific, and querying is restricted to same-origin, so that's not a security/privacy problem.